# Summing by a column which is not the index variable (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, sum

New to Python here (background is in SAS primarily).

I am trying to sum by a column which is not the index variable (in the below example, the index variable is 'department' and I am trying to sum by 'employee_fixed'). I can't make it the index variable because the index variable is being used as part of a for loop. Code below should make it clear.

```
#Creating dataset of departments you want to keep in your dataset
   #Setting df to only include departments specified
    cc = ['Furniture','Food','Clothing']
    for index in range(len(cc)): 
    df3_cc = df[df['department'].isin([cc[index]])]
    #set the department as the index variable so you can aggregate 
    df3_cc = df3_cc.set_index('department')
    df3_cc
    #Creating dataset of people who are NOT approved department
     #Setting df to only include the condition specified in "notapprov"
    notapprov = ['NO']
    df3_cc = df3_cc[df3_cc['appr_list_chc'].isin(notapprov)]
    df3_cc
    #drop unnecessary columns from dataframe
    df3_cc = df3_cc.drop(['fisc_yr_per'], axis=1)
    # sum up the hours based on the indexed departments
    # for those NOT approved to work that department and charging anyway
    # >40hrs in the latest period
    df3_cc = df3_cc[df3_cc['hrs_per'] >= 40].sum(level='employee_fixed') 
    #output to CSV
    df3_cc.to_csv(r"C:\Users\etc\table3_"+cc[index]+".csv")
```

The end result should be a separate CSV for each item in 'cc', with the summed number of hours of each employee (in 'employee_fixed') working in each department that is not authorized to work in that department (including only those who works >=40 hours in the current period).

Sample Input:
Department employee_fixed appr_list_chc hrs_per
Furniture John NO 45
Furniture Jacob NO 50
Food Jackie YES 100
Food Jeremy NO 75
FOOD Jim NO 10
Clothing Jonas NO 200
Clothing Jerry YES 10

Output:
table3_furniture.csv
Department employee_fixed appr_list_chc hrs_per
Furniture John NO 45
Furniture Jacob NO 50

table3_food.csv
Department employee_fixed appr_list_chc hrs_per
Food Jeremy NO 75

table3_food.csv
Department employee_fixed appr_list_chc hrs_per
Clothing Jonas NO 200

Thanks!

EDIT: found the answer! 
 df3_cc = df3_cc[df3_cc['hrs_per'] >= 40].sum(level='employee_fixed') 
became
 df3_cc = df3_cc[df3_cc['hrs_per'] >= 40]

Comment: I think it would be better if you also provided a sample input data with the expected output.

Comment: Sure! Will update the post

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all that was needed was to change one line:

```
df3_cc = df3_cc[df3_cc['hrs_per'] >= 40].sum(level='employee_fixed')
```

to:

```
df3_cc = df3_cc[df3_cc['hrs_per'] >= 40]
```

Comment: add context around your answer. Your answer was targeted by bot and labeled it "low quality" due to lack of context/explanation of your answer.